# Best (most efficient) way to show dynamic options menu in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Let's say we have many items in the UI. When a user clicks an item, the UI should present a popup/dialiog/overlay element with some options, actions and etc.

Currently I see two options:

1. Duplicate the overlay element for each item and hide it until associated item is clicked. Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urPww/1/

   `<div ng-show="currentItem">
           showing options for: {{currentItem.name}}
       </div>
       <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showOptions(item)">
           {{item.name}}
       </li>`
2. Place overlay UI once and keep track wich item was clicked last. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aVnPT/5/

   `<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showOptions(item)">
           {{item.name}}
           <span ng-show="item.showingOptions">
               <br/>showing options for: {{item.name}}
           </span>
       </li>`

The first solution is not efficient. Yet I can't figure out a clean way how to show overlay UI besides the clicked element in second one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single element by passing in `$event` as param to your `ng-click` function. Then can get position of mouse click relative to document

```
app.directive('container', function () {

    var offset = {
        left: 40,
        top: -20
    }
    return function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var $oLay = angular.element(document.getElementById('overlay'))

        scope.showOptions = function (item,$event) {       
            var overlayDisplay;
            if (scope.currentItem === item) {
                scope.currentItem = null;
                 overlayDisplay='none'
            }else{
                 scope.currentItem = item;
                overlayDisplay='block'
            }

            var overLayCSS = {
                left: $event.clientX + offset.left + 'px',
                top: $event.clientY + offset.top + 'px',
                display: overlayDisplay
            }

             $oLay.css(overLayCSS)
        }
    }
});
```

Am not sure if angular normalizes `clientX` and `clientY` the way jQuery does for different browsers. Not all browsers use same convention for event position properties Have removed `ng-show` from overlay element so it's style attributes can be controlled from directive, not by angular compiler due to timing, and given it an id.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jJyTf/

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 *could* work with a directive that dynamically places the options overlay alongside the clicked element using dom manipulation (see @charlietfl's answer). You end up with simpler HTML, but much more complicated js/angular code.

However I think option 1 is the right idea, and can just be cleaned up a bit. You can get rid of the directive, and have a controller method as simple as:

```
$scope.showOptions = function(item) {
    $scope.currentItem = item;
}
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qxF3A/3/

I'll gladly add some (minimal) duplication in my view/template if it greatly simplifies my controllers and avoids the need for a custom directive.

Comment: Because of the complexity of the project I'm working on I'd like to avoid putting UI logic in the controller. Anyways, thanks for your input.